# Inserting List as value in a Map

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, arraylist

I am getting a `List<String>` form hibernate which contains `completeFileAddress`.

`CompleteFileAddress` I'm getting from `List` is:

```
192.168.1.1/var/local/files/20140116/8800399421_4007_20140116_151718
192.168.1.2/var/local/files/monitor/20140115/9654180710_4006_20140115
192.168.1.1/var/local/files/20140116/8800399421_4007_20140116_120042
192.168.1.1/var/local/files/20140116/138_4007_20140116_122719
```

then I split `CompleteFileAddress` to get `IPAddress` and `FilePath` separately, and putting the values in a `Map<String, List<String>>` where key is `IPAddress` and value is List of `FilePath`.

My code is :

```
   List list = criteria.list();
            for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                String completeFileAddress = (String) (it.next());
                System.out.println("Complete add : " + completeFileAddress);
                if (completeFileAddress != null) {
                    int index = completeFileAddress.indexOf("/");
                    String serverIP = completeFileAddress.substring(0, index);
                    String filePath = completeFileAddress.substring(index, completeFileAddress.length()) + ".WAV";
                    filesMap.put(serverIP, sourceFileList); //sourceFileList is declared as an instance variable
                    sourceFileList.add(filePath);
                }
            }
        System.out.println("List '1' size :" + filesMap.get("192.168.1.1").size());
        System.out.println("List '2' size :" + filesMap.get("192.168.1.2").size());
```

I'm getting size of both `List` is `4`, but I want size of `List1 = 3` and `List2  = 1` as I have 3 files on server `192.168.1.1` and only one at `192.168.1.2`.

How can I achieve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are putting same `key`, `value` pair in map and referring same list for both keys.
- You can check if map contains key if it exists just retrieve value(i.e. list) and add `filePath` to that list
- If key does not exist then create new list and add `filePath` to newly created list, finally add `key`, `value` to map

Try this code

```
String serverIP = completeFileAddress.substring(0, index);
String filePath = completeFileAddress.substring(index, completeFileAddress.length()) + ".WAV";
if(filesMap.containsKey(serverIP))
{
   ArrayList<String> sourceList = filesMap.get(serverIP);
   sourceList.add(filePath);
}
else
{
   ArrayList<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();
   sourceList.add(filePath);
   filesMap.put(serverIP, sourceFileList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same List object for all entries in the map. Instead you must check for each serverIP if there already is an entry in the map. If there is an entry, add to the existing list. If there is no entry, create a new List and add the filePath to that one.

```
if (filesMap.get(serverIP) != null) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(filePath);
    filesMap.put(serverIP, list);
} else {
    filesMap.get(serverIP).add(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few Changes

```
List<String> sourceFileList = filesMap.get(serverIP);
if( sourceFileList == null ) {
   sourceFileList = new ArrayList() ;
}
sourceFileList.add(filePath);
filesMap.put(serverIP, sourceFileList);
```